# not single-group grouping function while using regr_slope

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

HI I try to run :

```
 select
  year,
  regr_slope(sum(sale_count),year) as slope,
from products
group by year
```

It throws "***00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"***" .When i delete year from select clause problem disapears. Shouldn't I be able to select column with which I'm grouping?

Oracle 11.2 sqldeveloper

ty for help !

Comment: ORA-00937: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00937.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're attempting to use a function ([REGR_SLOPE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions132.htm)) that can be either an aggregate (or analytical) function on the result of another aggregate (SUM) - use:

```
  SELECT x.year,
         REGR_SLOPE(sum_sales, x.year) AS slope
    FROM (SELECT y.year,
                 SUM(y.sale_count) AS sum_sales
            FROM PRODUCTS y
        GROUP BY y.year) x
GROUP BY x.year
```

Alternative using WITH clause (Oracle 9i+):

```
WITH sums AS (
     SELECT y.year,
            SUM(y.sale_count)
       FROM PRODUCTS y
   GROUP BY y.year)
  SELECT x.year,
         REGR_SLOPE(sum_sales, x.year) AS slope
    FROM sums x
GROUP BY x.year
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it like this?

```
select
   a.year
 , regr_slope(a.sale_count,a.year) as slope,
from (SELECT year
           , sum(sale_count) sale_count
        FROM products
      GROUP BY year) a
```